# Integer representation in Bit Fields

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

Bit-fields with type `signed int` are interpreted as `signed` .
Bit-fields whose type is `unsigned int` are interpreted as `unsigned` .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
/* This structure has one 8 bit field, whose type is unsigned int */
struct S
{
    unsigned int num: CHAR_BIT;
} x = { 255 };

int main(void)
{

    if(x.num - 256 > 0)
        printf("signed\n");
    else
        printf("unsigned\n");

    return 0;
}
```

On a 32-bit Windows machine, using Visual Studio 2008 this code outputs :
**"signed"**

What is type of the expression `(x.num - 256 > 0)` ?
if it is `unsigned int`, `unsigned int` cannot be represented as `int`, therefore it is require to be promoted to `unsigned int`, and result will be **"unsigned**" ?

Also, when I look in the assembly listing output :

```
mov eax, DWORD PTR _x
and eax, 255            ; 000000ffH
sub eax, 256            ; 00000100H
```

Thus:

```
x.num = 0x000000FF
x.num & = 0x0FF -> 0x000000ff
x.num - = 0x100 -> 0xFFFFFFFF

0xFFFFFFFF = -1
```

If this is true, then :

```
 if(-1 > 0)   
    printf("signed");  
 else   
    printf("unsigned");
```

Result must be **"unsigned"** ?

Can anyone properly explain these results ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to *integer promotions*, “If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int.” (This is 6.3.1.1:2 in C99).

An int can contain all values of an unsigned bit-field of width 8, so this unsigned bit-field is promoted to `int`. So `x.num` and `x.num - 256` both have type `int`.